# FAXCOMEXLib sends duplicate faxes

Tags: c#

We're using FAXCOMEXLib in our C# application which sends faxes using Windows Fax and Scan on Windows 7. The ultimate call is the call to ConnectedSubmit:

```
public List<string> Submit(FaxDocument doc)
{
    return new List<string>(doc.ConnectedSubmit(_faxServer));
}
```

However, when we look at the Outbox folder in Windows Fax and Scan during the transmission, we see the same fax appearing twice in the list. I checked the doc.Recipients.Count and I always see one in the Count property. What else could be causing this duplicate entry in the Outbox. This causes the user to send the same fax twice.

Comment: when you debug the code how many documents are in `doc` prior to executing the return line

Comment: When I look at doc it shows me "COM Object" as value. When I click the little plus sign I see its properties but one property called "Interface View", when I look at that it shows two children: FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument and FAXCOMEXLib.IFaxDocument2.

Comment: have you looked at this documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685958(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, but it does not give any extra info on what could be causing the duplicates. I see it would create one fax per recipient, but I only have one recipient.

Comment: double check your code based on what you have posted Ray it's hard to determine if you have not referenced it anywhere else in the code could you perhaps initialize the object to null to make sure